# Uncharged Conductor perpendicular to two infinite plates

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

If we have an uncharged conductor which is perpendicular to two infinite plates, one which is grounded and one with some set potential, then what is the potential of the uncharged conductor?

**The conductor is attached to the infinite plates, but you can assume it to be insulated from them by thin strips

I know a conductor has an equipotential surface, so the potential must be constant on it, but how does the field of the two infinite plates affect it? Because it is uncharged, I would think that as charges move through the electric field of the plates, they charge up the conductor, but I am not sure about this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "I would think that as charges move through the electric field of the plates..." Are you suggesting that the conductor is a) attached to the two infinite plates or is b) embedded in some conducting medium?

Comment: By "if we have an uncharged conductor which is perpendicular to two infinite plates" do you mean that the infinite plates are connected by the uncharged conductor?

Comment: @gmz see edit apologies

Comment: @Param_1729 see edit apologies

Comment: Likewise, charges will not move through the electric field created by the plates unless the medium is conductive.

Comment: @gmz so what does that mean for the potential of the conductor?

Comment: If the conductor is assumed cylindrical and the distance of its ends with the infinite plates (as they are separated thin strips) is assumed to be equal then it can be shown that the potential of the conductor is V/2 where V is the potential of the infinite plate which is not grounded. Note -  due to infinite plates there would be charge distribution on the conductor but the net charge on it will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

The conductor gets an induced surface-charge density. You can find an worked out example of this in Jackson's Classical Eletrodynamics, where he finds the induced charge density for a conducting sphere in a uniform eletric field.

Comment: It says I can use symmetry to figure out the potential, considering that the top plate is some potential and the bottom plate is 0. How would the induced charge density help me?